# Order ascending select options in Django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

Is there any way to order the form select list in a Django template

E.g. I got a select list like this:

```
<label for="{{ form.movie.id_for_label }}" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Movie:</label>
<select id="{{ form.movie.id_for_label }}" name="movie" class="form-control">
{% for x,y in form.fields.movie.choices %}
    <option value="{{ x }}">{{ y }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

and I want the output to be ordered by the movie's name ascending.

Comment: Try: for x,y in sorted(form.fields.movie.choices) ?

Comment: What is movie supposed to be? it would be better to do this in the form or model

Comment: movie is a foreign key, so the value (x) is the id, y is the representation, as I know. And movie object has a name attribute and that is I want to order by.